# Simple in ngRepeat in ngMap not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-map

I thought I had done this sort of thing before but I'm stuck trying to do something simple. This is my HTML using ngMap

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mapCtrl as map">
....
<map center="52.374, 4.899" zoom="12">
  <marker ng-repeat="m in map.data" title="{{m.name}}" position="{{m.lat}},{{m.lng}}"></marker>
</map>
```

and then I have a controller:

```
angular.module("myApp")
.controller('mapCtrl', function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.data = [
        {"name": "A1", "lat":52.38, "lng":4.9},
        {"name": "A2", "lat":52.39, "lng":4.87}
    ];

    return vm;
});
```

I'm ending up with 6 markers all at 0,0, rather than 2 in Amsterdam - See [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xyvH9CaLRmIK54p7kIjP?p=preview). Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case name conflict occurs. The map directive creates map object in scope over already defined controller object. So just rename `mapCtrl as map` to something else. For example `mapCtrl as mapCtrl`.